# is it possible to use solvePnP to find the actual position of 4 corner points?

Tags: python, opencv, math, 3d, computer-vision

I can use the solvepnp to find the rotation and translation of (0,0,0) of the cam frames and world frame.

```
mtx = np.array([
[463.889   ,       0       ,    320],
[0         ,       463.889,     240],
[0         ,       0   ,         1 ],
])
dist = np.array([0.0,0,0,0,0])


objp = np.zeros((4,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:2,0:2].T.reshape(-1,2)

#objp = array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.], 
#   [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
#   [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
#   [ 1.,  1.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
# let assume the square len is 1cm.

corners2 = np.float32([ [[498,136]] , [[558,138]],  [[505,184]], [[569,186]]])
retval, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.solvePnP(objp, corners2, mtx, dist)

imgpts, jac = cv2.projectPoints(axis, rvecs, tvecs, mtx, dist)
```

Is tvecs corresponding to the position of (0,0,0) from camera frame?

How can I also find the translations of the other 3 points?  ([ 1.,  0.,  0.], [ 0.,  1.,  0.],   [ 1.,  1.,  0.])

in other words, can I get the actual position of all the points in corners2?

Comment: With `rvec` (`Rodrigues()` allows to get the rotation matrix from the rotation vector) and `tvec`, you can build the `3x4` transformation matrix that allows to convert a 3D point expressed in the object frame into the camera frame: `P_cam = [R | t] P_obj`. See transformation matrix, homogeneous transformation matrix topics.

Answer (score 4):

> Is tvecs corresponding to the position of (0,0,0) from camera frame?

In the OpenCV documentation you can find the answer to this.

> - rvec – Output rotation vector (see Rodrigues() ) that, together with    tvec , brings points from the model coordinate system to the
>     camera    coordinate system.
> - tvec – Output translation vector.

Here it tells you that it brings points from the model coordinate system to the camera one, this means that whatever your coordinate system your points have, it will find the translation and rotation needed to move it to a position which can be projected to an image plane and produce the 2D image.

For your question, it depends... if you assume your points come from a camera which looks at them and generates them with the camera as the (0,0,0) then yes. If the origin is in the middle of your points and by camera you mean the one that generates the image where you get your 2D points, then this tvecs is origin towards this camera.

> How can I also find the translations of the other 3 points? ([ 1., 0., 0.], [ 0., 1., 0.], [ 1., 1., 0.])

Quite easy, first you need to create a transformation matrix out of the rvecs and tvecs. rvecs is in Rodrigues and you may use that function to obtain the rotation matrix (3x3) and you put the translation as column vector next to it and below it a row of 0 and 1 in the last position like this:

```
                 R11 R12 R13 T1

Transformation = R21 R22 R23 T2

                 R31 R32 R33 T3

                 0   0   0   1
```

Now you put the points in homogeneous coordinates (basically a 1 under in an extra row. Then you multiply it.

```
P = 1
    0
    0
    1

Transformation * P
```

You can do this with all the points you want :) In this case it will give you a 4x1 vector that represents your 3D point and the last part (in this case) it will be 1 and can be removed to return to a 3D point. In other cases, the last component divides the other components (to make it 1) and it is removed as well.

As a final note, you can also obtain the pose of the camera with this doing it continuously it can be tracked.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

so it is like this? thanks a lot.

```
rotMat,_ = cv2.Rodrigues(rvecs)
T0 = np.zeros((4, 4))
T0[:3,:3] = rotMat
T0[:4,3] = [0, 0, 0, 1]
T0[:3,3] =  np.transpose(tvecs)

p0 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])
z0 = np.dot(T0, p0);

p1 = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])
z1 = np.dot(T0, p1);

p2 = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])
z2 = np.dot(T0, p2);

p3 = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1])
z3 = np.dot(T0, p3);
```

Comment: I think that will be the correct code, does it give you the expected answer? BTW, to add more information to your question please use the edit button, not the answer button :) I would suggest to delete this one, not to confuse other people and add it as part of your question. Also, it is better to leave a comment, I entered here today by chance, but most most of the time I do not re enter, but with a comment I get notified.